# Getting error Instance of 'tuple' has no 'difference' member (no-member)

Tags: python, set, pylint

I am trying to pass a python script and it is showing error with a = b.difference(c). Basically pylint fails for all lines where I have used set operations like symmetric_difference and difference. Don't know what is the issue. Should I use the for loop method to achieve what I am trying to achieve instead of set operations.

Comment: Please provide a code example with the statement in context of relevant definitions. What is `b`? What is `c`? The error indicates that `b` is a `tuple` where you seem to think it is a `set`.

Comment: Yes @Grismar, b and c are sets